# Get an error when trying to install Matlab 2014a on Debian

Tags: debian, software-installation, java, header-file, matlab

I'm trying to install Matlab 2014a on Debian Testing. When I run the install script with

```
sudo ./install -javadir /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/
```

I get this output

```
Preparing installation files ...
Installing ...
Error: dl failure on line 894
Error: failed /tmp/mathworks_11967/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so, because /tmp/mathworks_11967/bin/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: invalid ELF header
Finished
```

I'm installing from an .iso, running this script from it's root directory (matlab).
 `libstdc++.so.6` is in `matlab/bin/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6`.

Here's my java version:

```
$java -version
java version "1.7.0_85"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.1) (7u85-2.6.1-3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.85-b03, mixed mode)
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I have been pulling my hair out for hours, and I can't use Python or Octave as Matlab is required for a course I'm taking. I've scoured forums for hours, the only other person with the exact same error as me was [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327560/how-to-fix-dl-failure-invalid-elf-header-error-while-installing-matlab/676938#676938) and they never got an answer.

**EDIT**: Solved it. First thing: do not attempt to install a version of matlab on an operating system it does not officially support. 2014a only supports Debian Squeeze and Ubuntu 12.04, 13.04, and 13.10.

I set up a VM running Ubuntu 12.04.5, extracted the .iso on my host machine and copied the directory to my VM's home folder. I did *not* mount the iso.

Then I had to remove `matlab/bin/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6` and replace it with the file named `libstdc++.so.6.0.17` in the same folder. `libstdc++.so.6` is supposed to be a symbolic link to the other library, however if you try to mount the iso directly it often breaks the link and replaces it with a text file.

When I was attempting to install Matlab by mounting it on the VM, I got the same error. I managed to remove it by replacing the copy of `libstdc++.so.6` with the one located in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libstdc++.so`. Then I began to get java errors, and it turns out that the `matlab/java/jar/professionalinstaller.jar` file was corrupted. I had extracted the iso before I began all of this, which is how I could go back to before that jar became corrupted. Hopefully this post is of use to some other poor soul forced to use Matlab in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem while installing the 2013 version on Debian 8 using an iso image.

#### Solution

The solution that worked for me consists in renaming the `libstdc++.so.6` file to `libstdc++.so.6.0.13` in the iso image' `bin/` directory.
After that, I issued the command:

```
# ./install -x
```

to start graphical installation.
Finally, it worked!